# Convert large binary string to decimal string

Tags: c#

I've got a large text, containing a number as a binary value. e.g '123' would be '001100010011001000110011'. EDIT: should be 1111011

Now I want to convert it to the decimal system, but the number is too large for `Int64`.

So, what I want: Convert a large binary string to decimal string.

Comment: My calculator says that 1100010011001000110011₂ equals 3224115₁₀, not 123₁₀. 3224115₁₀ is not too large for Int64.

Comment: Have you googled? I found this: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/123317-convert-binary-decimal-string.html

Comment: How did you get from 123 decimal to 001100010011001000110011 binary?

Comment: Smells like homework, who would read that >20 digit number?

Comment: No homework, and i google for that 123 on ascii to bin. Oh, and the numbers represents filecontents. EDIT: 123 should be 1111011

Comment: @MikeW three bytes: 49, 50, 51; as chars: 123

Comment: Thanks fury, thats the answer.

Comment: If you have trouble fitting the numbers in `long`, you should be careful with `Math.Pow(...)`, since floating point numbers have a limited value range too (and a limited precision, which can quickly lead to wrong and – even worse, since it's not easy to find these bugs – inconsistent results)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This'll do the trick:

```
public string BinToDec(string value)
{
    // BigInteger can be found in the System.Numerics dll
    BigInteger res = 0;

    // I'm totally skipping error handling here
    foreach(char c in value)
    {
        res <<= 1;
        res += c == '1' ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: OP said it's too big for even int64, so he wants a decimal string.

Comment: Yeah, changed it to match his needs.

Comment: BigInteger is in System.Numerics which as not referenced by default.

Comment: @MikeW: That's why I inserted the location in the sample while you were typing your comment ;)