# Convert BigInteger binary to BigInteger number

Tags: c#, binary, biginteger

Currently I am using the `Long` integer type. I used the following to convert from/to binary/number:

```
Convert.ToInt64(BinaryString, 2); // Convert binary string of base 2 to number
Convert.ToString(LongNumber, 2); // Convert long number to binary string of base 2
```

Now the numbers I am using have exceeded 64 bit, so it has started using BigInteger. I can't seem to find the equivalent of the code above.

How can I convert from a BinaryString that have over 64bits to a BigInteger number and vice versa?

---

The references in the answer contains the answer I want, but I am having some trouble in the conversion from Number to Binary.

I have used the following code which is available in the first reference:

```
    public static string ToBinaryString(this BigInteger bigint)
    {
        var bytes = bigint.ToByteArray();
        var idx = bytes.Length - 1;

        // Create a StringBuilder having appropriate capacity.
        var base2 = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 8);

        // Convert first byte to binary.
        var binary = Convert.ToString(bytes[idx], 2);

        // Ensure leading zero exists if value is positive.
        if (binary[0] != '0' && bigint.Sign == 1)
        {
            base2.Append('0');
        }

        // Append binary string to StringBuilder.
        base2.Append(binary);

        // Convert remaining bytes adding leading zeros.
        for (idx--; idx >= 0; idx--)
        {
            base2.Append(Convert.ToString(bytes[idx], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }

        return base2.ToString();
    }
```

The result I got was wrong:

```
100001000100000000000100000110000100010000000000000000000000000000000000 ===>  2439583056328331886592
2439583056328331886592 ===> 0100001000100000000000100000110000100010000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you put the resulted binary string under each other, you will notice that the conversion is correct and that the problem is that there is a leading zero from the left:

```
100001000100000000000100000110000100010000000000000000000000000000000000
0100001000100000000000100000110000100010000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I tried reading the explanation provided in the code and changing it, but no luck.

I was later able to solve it by changing the following in the code:

```
        // Ensure leading zero exists if value is positive.
        if (binary[0] != '0' && bigint.Sign == 1)
        {
            base2.Append('0');

            // Append binary string to StringBuilder.
            base2.Append(binary);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing built-in in the .NET framework.

Fortunately, the Stack Overflow community has already solved both problems:

- BigInteger → Binary: [BigInteger to Hex/Decimal/Octal/Binary strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14048476/87698)
- Binary → BigInteger: [Convert large binary string to decimal string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774083/87698)

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look at the problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reference on MSDN about BigIntegers;

*[BigInteger Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Also there is a post to convert from binary to biginteger: *[Conversion of a binary representation stored in a list of integers (little endian) into a Biginteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947412/conversion-of-a-binary-representation-stored-in-a-list-of-integers-little-endia)*

This example is from MSDN.

```
string positiveString = "91389681247993671255432112000000";
string negativeString = "-90315837410896312071002088037140000";
BigInteger posBigInt = 0;
BigInteger negBigInt = 0;

try {
   posBigInt = BigInteger.Parse(positiveString);
   Console.WriteLine(posBigInt);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.",
                     positiveString);
}

if (BigInteger.TryParse(negativeString, out negBigInt))
  Console.WriteLine(negBigInt);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.",
                      negativeString);

// The example displays the following output:
//   9.1389681247993671255432112E+31
//   -9.0315837410896312071002088037E+34
```

Comment: Those are not strings of binary digits.  The question is pretty specific to dealing with "string of base 2"

Comment: There is an answer in this post, is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947412/conversion-of-a-binary-representation-stored-in-a-list-of-integers-little-endia

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful.

**Usage:**

```
string someString = "-1101010001"; // More examples: 1_1111_0101, +100101101
bool success = TryParseBinary(someString, out BigInteger outBigInt);
```

**The Function:**

```
static bool TryParseBinary(ReadOnlySpan<char> input, out BigInteger result)
{
    int inputLen = input.Length;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(inputLen + 7) / 8];
    int outputBitPosition = 0; // The current bit we 
                               // are writing to.

    // If it starts with a '-' then set 
    // negative rawValue to zero.
    bool isNeg = input[0] == '-'; // 0x2D;

    // If starting with a - or + then 
    // set headPosition to 1.
    int headPosition = isNeg | input[0] == '+' ? 1 : 0;

    int tailPosition = inputLen - 1;
    for (; tailPosition >= headPosition; tailPosition--)
    {
        switch (input[tailPosition])
        {
            case '1':
                bytes[outputBitPosition >> 3] |= 
                    (byte)(1 << (outputBitPosition & 0x7));
                goto case '0';

            case '0':
                outputBitPosition++;
                break;

            // Allow commas, '_' (i.e., 1111_1111_0000), 
            // and spaces
            case ',' or '_' or ' ':  
                break;

            default:
                result = new BigInteger(0);
                return false; // Function was not successful - 
                              // unsupported char found
        }
    }

    // If the number is negative, let's perform 
    // two's complement: (1) invert the 
    // bits (2) add 1
    if (isNeg)
    {
        int byteCount = bytes.Length;

        //   (1) Invert the bits
        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] ^= 0xff;
        }

        //   (2) Increment the LSB and increment more 
        //       significant bytes as needed.
        bytes[0]++;
        for (int i = 0; bytes[i] == 0; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 >= byteCount)
            {
                break;
            }

            bytes[i + 1]++;
        }
    }

    result = new(bytes, !isNeg);

    // Return true if success. If no 0/1 bits 
    // found then return false.
    return outputBitPosition != 0;
}
```