# Converting a binary string to BigInteger

Tags: c#, biginteger

I'm trying to convert a large binary string to a `BigInteger` number in C#. After doing some research a line such as the one below should work but for the 2 reasons below it isn't. Am I missing something?

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("100101000111111110000", 2);
```

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan'
>
> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: Neither the `BigInteger` constructor nor its `Parse` method have an overload that accepts a `string` and numeric base.  Are you sure you're looking at .NET documentation, and not `BigInteger` from Java or some other framework?

Comment: Your code is Java, not C#.

Comment: I don't see a constructor accepting string and integer for [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0#constructors). Where have you found this code? Is this from [Java one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int))?

Comment: Would it work in Java then?

Comment: Related: [Faster way to convert large binary string to BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333862/faster-way-to-convert-large-binary-string-to-biginteger)

Comment: @UniqueHold Yes, it will work in Java.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias but the answer shows exactly what OP needed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias we can use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612030/2501279) if you prefer)) Though it links previous one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Linq and get the result via `Aggregate`:

```
using.System.Linq;

...

BigInteger bi = "100101000111111110000"
  .Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (s, a) => (s << 1) + a - '0');
```

Comment: Thanks! This one did the trick. I didn't know it could be used this way. I appreciate your response.

Comment: That works... so long as the source string consists solely of `0` and `1`.

Comment: @NicholasCarey OP specifies binary string. I assume it should consist only of 1s and 0es, no?

Comment: @GuruStron — Do you trust your input? I don't

Comment: @NicholasCarey it depends.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-6.0) show the different constructors.

But none of those constructors take a `string` and then an `int` as parameters. That's what the errors are about. Where did you get the idea the constructor took those arguments?

From what I could see, `BigInteger` cannot be called this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BigInteger bi = (BigInteger) 1341231.8523;
```

The above would cast your double to a decimal. However, the BigInteger Struct does not have functionality to convert from binary to integer. It looks like you used the BigInteger Java class functionality.

Comment: I don't see any `double` in the question, so how does this answer the q?

Answer (score -2):

This `BigInteger` belongs to `Org.BouncyCastle.Math` namespace in `BouncyCastle.Crypto` assembly.

- Install it via NuGet (or in visual studio via NuGet manager)

```
Install-Package Portable.BouncyCastle -Version 1.9.0
```

- Usage (convert a binary string to decimal)

```
var bi = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("100101000111111110000", 2);
var decimalString = bi.ToString();
var b = double.TryParse(decimalString, out double d);
```

Comment: The BigInteger struct is in the System.Numerics namespace.

Comment: Really, And what if there is another BigInteger in another assembly that takes first parameter as string and the second one as int? If you read the question well, it says "After doing some research a line such as the one below should work but".. but could not run it.. so I've make it clear why he could not run it..

Comment: Considering BigInteger is in the native System.Numerics namespace, should we be quick to jump to the conclusion that he was using the third party BouncyCastle.Crypto assembly? However, your suggestion does work. It looks like this piece of functionality in BouncyCastle was ported from Java.

Comment: He uses nothing, he just found a piece of code out there and wonders why it's not working..  As the only explanation for the existence of such `BigInteger(string, int);` is that it belongs to the popular bountycastel assembly: "jumping fast" to a correct explanation is smart, isn't it?

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman I don't agree with your last comment - OP for example could have been confused by some java code, for example. Just tweak the answer wording a bit (to something like "you can use BigInt from....") and I would argue it will have much more appeal.

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman Good point. Although I suspect it is more likely he found an answer for Java while Googling or searching for answers here.